# Do any of you know who is the author of this graphic?

Tags: art

My fiance likes a particular artist and he told me once he'd like to get a book of his work. I managed to get a pic of one of his pieces but I can't find out who the author is. I know he has a page/blog where he posts his art, and also that there's some book available on Amazon with his work.[image]
Does any of you know what is the author's name?

Answer (score 5):

The artist is Simon Stålenhag.

http://www.simonstalenhag.se/

[image]

[Here's the Amazon link to his 2 books.](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1?ie=UTF8&text=Simon%20St%C3%A5lenhag&search-alias=books&field-author=Simon%20St%C3%A5lenhag&sort=relevancerank)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been really wanting to get these books for him on Christmas.

Comment: No problem! His art is excellent. I really love how he tells a story with his scenes.

Comment: @lex If you could, please mark this as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Did you immediately recognize the shown art or its style, or were you able to find it through a reversed image search?

Comment: @usr2564301Recognized it, I actually own his first book. His art also pops up A LOT in wallpaper dumps because it's so unique.